# How to fetch 1:M entity from parent class with limit?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have an entity class with multiple one-to-many entity classes.
All child classes having fetch type `FetchType.EAGER`.
I have to fetch them with a **limit** and with parent class. 
How can i do it in Hibernate JPA?

Answer (score 2):

Make the `OneToMany` relationship `FetchType.LAZY` and then simply use [JPA queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs40/full/html/ejb3_overview_query.html) with [Query.setMaxResults()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29).

Comment: I have wanted to fetch child objects with parent. If i use LAZY fetching then i have to retrieve child separately after parent.

Comment: As I understand, you have a bidirectional relationship. The `OneToMany` part should be `FetchType.LAZY` and the `ManyToOne` `EAGER`, so that the parent is always fetched.

Answer (score 0):

My personal hint, it's just to avoid eager associations, but if this is a requirement. I could try max_fetch_depth property.
Have a look on the [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html) to know how it works.